# Uppercase in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to make a text-transform into a table which I create with the library of TCPDF for PHP, but I can't make the transform. I've read that the library doesn't have the support for some class of CSS, so I'm here to ask if that is true or if someone has a solution.

```
$bloque4 = <<<EOF

<style>
    .uppercase {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>

    <table class="uppercase">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight: bold; width:140px"><img src="images/back.jpg"></td>
        
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="font-weight: bold; padding:5px 10px;">
    
        <tr>
        
        <td style="font-weight: bold; border: 0.7px solid #000000; background-color:white; width:250px;">Condiciones en que se recibe: $respuestaVenta[condiciones] <br><br> Piezas faltantes: $respuestaVenta[pzasFaltantes] <br><br> Piezas maltratadas y/o rotas: $respuestaVenta[pzasRotas]</td>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; border: 0.7px solid #000000; background-color:white; width:290px; text-align:right;">Tipo de servicio: $respuestaVenta[tipoReparacion]
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>

EOF;

$pdf->writeHTML($bloque4, false, false, false, false, '');
```

problem with the new array `$respuestaVenta = array_map('strtoupper', $respuestaVenta);`

[image]

this is the way how I print the resulto before use the `array_map`

```
<td style="font-weight: bold; border: 0.7px solid #000000; background-color:white; width:135px; text-align:center;">$respuestaVenta[descripcion]</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned that you won't be able to do it with CSS, then just capitalize your array with PHP before you use it.

```
$respuestaVenta = array_map('strtoupper', $respuestaVenta);
$bloque4 = <<<EOF
//  ...
```

Comment: but, if I want to apply to all the table is the same way? because I've some other text in the table which I want to transform

Comment: As far as the static text, if you want it to be uppercase, wouldn't you just type it in uppercase?

Comment: Well, you're right, but I put a lot of blocks to fill out the PDF, so I was trying to find a way without having to rewrite everything. but to make more easy, I'm going to requrite all haha, another consult is how can I print the result of the `array_map`? because if I use `$respuestaVenta[pzasFaltantes]` show me an error

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. There may be another way, but I don't know it. What error does it give you? I would expect it to be basically the same array as before, just transformed to uppercase.

Comment: I edit the question with the screen and how i print the result before use the array_map

Comment: Is that image a var_dump of that array after mapping strtoupper? It looks like those indexes are defined. I must be missing something.

Comment: is a print_r after the mapping,

Comment: I've some data in json and make a mistake with the mapping